# Signing and submitting app without Mac

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I'm developing an iPhone + iPad app for a client who doesn't have a Mac and are not willing to give their Apple ID to me so that I could sign and submit the app for them.

Is there any way for them submitting the app giving that I provide them all the necessary screenshots and Xcode project folder?

I somewhere read (can't find again) that I could also send them Signing Tool and that will do the job. Is this correct?

I don't have a Dev license.

**Edit**
The client has the Dev License.

Comment: Will this be on the `App Store` or for an `Ad-hoc` distribution? And what license do you have?

Comment: @eggy App Store distribution

Comment: What about installing MacOSX on virtual machine on windows? They could also try installing hackintoshs.

Answer (score 0):

If you can trust on a third party then you can go with App Cloud -

http://support.brightcove.com/en/app-cloud/docs/step-step-guide-publishing-apple-app-store-using-windows

It requires some info from you and will compile and submit app for you.

I didn't used this but seems it will work in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have great difficulty submitting an app without a dev licence. For starters, you'll need to purchase a iOS Developer account to verify your system as well as an additional iOS testing platforms you are using.

You should start by creating your own Apple ID [here](http://store.apple.com/au/browse/account/home). From there, you can provision your system and submit an App (once you have obtained the correct keys).

Comment: The client has the paid dev license. And I have the app ready to be signed and submitted.